# Javascript object remove specific key

Tags: javascript

I'm having problem with this object array. I need to remove the object who match the removeVal.I't doesn't remove. See attached photos which is highlighted in red. I need to remove that all.

[image]

```
var removeVal = $(this).attr('href');    
         $.each(product_json, function(key, val){

                  if( key == removeVal) {
                        val.splice(key);
                   }

              });
```

[image]

Comment: make sure removeVal  and key's data type should same

Comment: show us product_json data

Comment: you can use `filter` function .

Comment: That is the product_json on the picture.

Comment: what is the removeVal you are passing

Comment: 0 on that case.

Comment: I need also to remove the highlighted in red. What will I do?

Comment: you splice the `product_json` not the index object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will helps you if i understand correctly,

```
var removeVal = $(this).attr('href'); 

delete product_json[removeVal]
```

Comment: except delete wont really completely delete that object index it just change its value to undefined

Answer (score 1):

Probably you meant something like

```
$.each(product_json, function(key, val){
  if(val == removeVal) {
    product_json.splice(key, 1);
  }
});
```

But that since `splice` reindexes, when removing an item the next one won't be checked, but might need to be removed too.

The proper way is using `filter`:

```
product_json = product_json.filter(function(val) {
  return val != removeVal;
});
```

Comment: I need to remove the highlighted red. I don't care if it reindex. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think product_json looks like that image you show.

Then,

shouldn't the code be like below?

```
var removeVal = $(this).attr('href');    
$.each(product_json, function(key, val){
    // val is an array
    for( var i in val ) {
        // val[i] is also an array
        for( var j in val[i] ) {
            // val[i][j] is a value
            if( val[i][j] == removeVal ) {
                val.splice( key );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

To be more specific,

I need you to explain what the product_json is

and sample of $(this).attr( 'href' )

and why those arrays in that image look like that.